# Found "HowToRemove.html" on Windows task bar

Tags: windows-10, virus-removal

While scrolling through the apps on my Windows 10 laptop, I found the above an app called "HowToRemove.html". I have never seen it before and I am pretty sure it wasn't there when I bought the laptop.

Is this dangerous? If so, what should I do? Has anyone seen this before?

[image]

Comment: who know? delete it. not likely.

Comment: See what file the shortcut leads to, and open it in a text editor. I'd guess it's probably uninstall instructions for a program you have on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Enter Safe Mode on your PC, to do this open the start menu and click the power button, hold shift and click reboot. Select Troubleshooting, Advanced Options, Startup Settings. Then select the restart, your PC will reboot and bring up startup options, select #4 (safe mode).

I assume you have Windows 10 by the way ;)

Select the Cortana-search and search for Disk Cleanup, and run that.

If you have malware scanners use those and if possible get a new one because if it is a virus your current one didn't pick it up. I'd recommend Malwarebytes.

If that doesn't pick anything up and the HowToRemove.html is still there it might be worth trying to scan it individually if you're able to. If not just delete it this way:

In the Cortana-search type "uninstall" and it should come up with a control panel item called "Change or remove Programs". Run that and find the HowToRemove.html through there, then reboot.

Hope I could help

Answer (score 0):

I would go to the properties and see what file it opens first. But do not run it.